# Doctrine 2.5.4 ArrayCache not found after installation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to update Doctrine version and installing it from archives from Doctrine web site. 
After installation I have four folders:

- Common
- DBAL
- ORM
- Symfony

In the Doctrine folder.

And get an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache' not found in
>   [ROOT_PATH]\Vendors\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup.php
>   on line 145

There is indeed no Cache folder in Common, though it did exist in the previous version of Doctrine I had.

I am not using Symfony nor Composer.

Answer (score 0):

I just used `composer require symfony/cache` and it works.

Comment: This does NOT solve this problem. Perhaps you can use symfony/cache to replace ArrayCache, but if so, plz supply an example.